# problems when make a web service as an alternative to dll

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, visual-studio-2008, dll

Q:

Recently , i face some problems, i have a dll common among a lot of applications,and any change to this dll require to build it, copy and paste it in each bin folder of these applications ,and add the new reference so i decided to convert this dll to a web service in stead to overcome this overload.. 
I make a web service application contains set of web services(mapping to each class).

I face some problems here:

- In the original dll, there are
  classes use  methods exist in other
  classes in the same dll, and  i face problems when i
  tried to use web service methods in
  other web service class.how to fix
  this problem.
- In the original dll there are set of
  static classes with static
  methods.how to make the equivalent in
  my web service application.
- Any overload method cause a problem
  in my web service.
- When using `Dictionary<string, string>`
  as a parameter in my method.

**Note**:the original `dll` contains the connections to the data base. Is converting it to web service is the optimum solution?which one is faster in my case a web service or the dll?Should i tend to `WCF` instead of?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my applications I usually have all related projects in the same solution. But when I need to use projects across applications I replace the project for a dll reference.

Because I use Subversion I solve the problem of copying the dll by adding an external property do my libs folder, referencing the build of the dll.

If the external dll is updated very often than you probably need a continuous integration system to handle that for you.

Comment: what i need is: i have a common dll among set of web applications , if i change the dll this require to copy and paste in the bin of the dependent applications,Adding the dll as a project to my application solve a part of the problem , but what a bout when i wanna to publish ,then if i change in the dll i have to publish all the dependent applications again.

Comment: If you are using unsigned assemblies you can just publish the changed dll. You don't need to publish the entire applications as long as you don't change the dll version the applications are expecting.

If you want to automatically do a mass deploy of the dll then you could perhaps do it with a copying script.

Comment: the problem not in publish the whole application or just the dll, because if i have to publish the dll , no problem in the publish at all. the problem is: i have to publish even the dll in all applications depend on that dll with any change to it. is there any solution enable me ,when make any change to this dll all the applications see that change without copy and paste or publish operation.

Comment: I can't think of any solution for your applications to know the dll changed without copying or publishing. If the applications are deployed in different places then you need to publish the changed dll, whether by pushing the new dll with every build or pulling the new dll on demand. If you use continuous integration you can push the new dll automatically whenever you build. I think the easiest way is to make the script copying the dll to all application and run that whenever you need to deploy it.

Answer (score 1):

I usually add project reference and keep all my projects under single solution, so I do not have file copy issue. You might be missing project reference, instead you could have used assembly reference. Verify that first.

First advice, don't create a web service if you don't know what it is and how it can be used. People tend to think everything is a web service since creating a web service in WCF is so easy by using visual studio tools. Since you ask like converting DLL to a web service, I assume that you are beginning with learning web service.

All you need is kind of continues integration system otherwise a simple build system which does the build for you and it copies the files wherever depended applications folder. Hence you can save your time for coping files manually. When you do this, you will not have any of those 4 problems you have mentioned.

If you are lazy enough to learn the build system, simply write a batch file that would copy the files for you. I do have batch files which does xcopy files.

Comment: thanks a lot , this fix my problem..
two more questions please,
1- i don't know what you mean by `build system` , Do u mean source control or not?
2- adding all my dependent projects to same solution as you said solve the problem , what is the benefit of  a batch file , i don't need to copy files , Did you mean some thing else?

Comment: what i need is: i have a common dll among set of web applications , if i change the dll this require to copy and paste in the bin of the dependent applications,Adding the dll as a project to my application solve a part of the problem , but what a bout when i wanna to publish ,then if i change in the dll i have to publish all the dependent applications again.