# pre build and post build events

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, dll, batch-file

Q:

I'm still searching how to perform what i wanna to do ..
I have a `DLL`(set of classes contain connection to data base ,...etc) which is common among several applications .**My goal is**: any change or modification to this DLL reflect to all the applications use this DLL.i don't want to republish the DLL in all applications with each change.
I make the following but invain:

1- trying to put the DLL in [GAC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6176105/418343) .

2-trying to convert the [DLL to web service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6185791/418343).

3-put the DLL as a project in the same solution for each application use it.this partially solve the problem.

now i read about pre-build and post-build events in visual studio . i want to know how to use these events and how to write a batch to execute what i want to do.i will be grateful if there is some code or scripts do identify how to solve the problem.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GAC will work fine for you. HOWEVER you must trigger a recompile in your applications.

Also if you compile other applications that use this library as a project reference, they will update their reference when you perform the compile and copy the updated library.

If you all reference the gac - drop the file into the gac, but you will then add a local reference that is not the gac - visual studio will detect this library is in the gac and if you look at the properties of your reference it will show CopyLocal=false which means it will use the GAC and not the local copy.

MAKE SURE all of your application references have CopyLocal=false for this library.
You do not need post build events for this.
But remember - any application that uses the gac library will need a recompile triggered to pick up the change. Add a blank line to the web.config for example - that will trigger the recompile on the spot.  Without a recompile, the changes will not be picked up in the gac.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using source control?  SVN has externals for this sort of thing...

Comment: iam using `tfs` source control

Comment: Here is a way to simulate svn externals in tfs: http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2010/08/simulating-svn-externals-feature-in-tfs.html